# python - self - required positional argument

Tags: python, self

here is my code:

my file which I start:

```
 from SQLhandler import SQLhandler 
 D = SQLhandler.loadProject(4711)
```

a part of my SQLhandler file:

```
class SQLhandler(object):
   db = pymysql.connect(... )

   def loadProject(self, project_id):
    #do some stuff
```

I want to use db in other functions, so I put it on the class level and added a "self" to loadProject. Now the second line in my start file throws an error:

```
"loadProject() missing 1 required positional argument: 'project_id'"
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `self` is the instance of `SQLhandler` that `loadProject()` is being called from. In your example, you are not creating an instance, so the first argument (which is expected to be `self`), is being assigned from `4711`, and then there is no `project_id`. Perhaps you meant: `D = SQLhandler().loadProject(4711)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your class definition you need to have a `def __init__(self, ... params):` function that tells how to initialize a new instance. Try including something along the lines of

```
def __init__(self, project_id):
    self.project_id = project_id
```